# spawn multiple threads in loop and knowing when all finished to do certain task

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to spawn multiple threads in loop for configured no. of sites and then each thread has multiple child threads. After finishing all threads I need to do certain task to save data into database. How I come to know whether all task has finished.
my current code:

```
List<SocialDataConfig> configList = SetConfiguration();
foreach (SocialDataConfig config in configList)
{
    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        FetchSocialData(config);
    }).Start();
}
// save fetched data into database and log fetched information in database

private void FetchSocialData(SocialDataConfig config)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < config.ThreadCount; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            FetchData(54764876, config);
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own threads you can use the new Task library in C#.

You can then use something like this:

```
int n = 10;

// Construct started tasks
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(action, i);
}

// Wait for all the tasks to finish.
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Here is the [MSDN documentation on WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) with a complete example.